# Div overflow inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<div class="one">
    <h2>Title that can be quite long and I don't know it's height</h2>
    <div class="two">Content that can overflow and that needs to be scrolled (but the title needs to remain up so that won't scroll</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.one{height: 250px; width: 120px;}
.two{overflow:auto;}
```

But I can't get .two to do the scroll. I don't know the height of .two or h2. Also I only want .two to do the scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made the http://jsfiddle.net/zm8Lj/ for you. Please take a look.

Comment: The perfect solution would be that the scroll only covered the area actually being scrolled but this will certainly solve the isue at the moment. Thank you very much!

Comment: Solutions on stack overflow shouldn't be a link. Someone should edit this so that the solution code is written within the answer's text.

Answer (score 1):

you mean this ?

```
.two{overflow:auto; height:200px;}
```

Comment: I said I don't know the height of .two

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an heigth for `two`.
Calculate the `div.two` height depending on the `h2` height.

```
$('div.two').height($('div.one').height()-$('h2').height());
```

See it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/FQwbG/

Comment: I was hoping for a non js solution I'll have to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't your title don't move from top, wrap it with div and give it `position: fixed; top: 0px; lwft: 0px;`